# Best way to share moving map location

Tags: android, database, google-maps-api-3

I have an application running on several mobile phones. I'd like to share the current position of each phone with the others and updating this location when they move.
I thought creating an external database (mysql) and asking the application to send its current location (geoPoint) to the database every 5 seconds (for example).
Is it the best way to proceed? If many many phones run this application, it will cause a lot of requests to the database at the same time...
Do you have any idea about the best way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do you need to store position information in DB? Why not create simple server in node.js, which just hold user last position?
2. You can use https://www.meteor.com/ . It's designed to share data live across all participants.

Comment: In fact... I didn't know Node.js :( Thanks a lot, I'll have a look as soon as possible!
And thanks for your link as well!!

Comment: @user2080786 you can create java server, which will get requests about users updated location and in return gives location of all participants. Android -MyLocation->Server-UpdateLocationTable()->-Return:LocationOfAllParticipants->Android